# div Margins with display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to manipulate divs without using float, using `display: inline-block;` in my css allows me to get the siblings next to each other within a container div, but with inline-block, I can't space them apart using `margin-left: 20px;`, `margin-right :20px;` ... and so on.

I'm sure there's a really simple solution, even if it doesn't involve using `display: inline-block;`, I just want to avoid floats and preferably avoid padding too.

Comment: Try using [FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: While using flexbox may well be a better approach, inline-blocks respect margins so you should have been able to space them apart. But since you didn't post any code, we can't show you where you were going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can try flex-box method to create space between two div which is inside a div (I conclude that from your question )

```css
.parent{
border:2px solid red;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-around;

}
.parent div{
border:3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">
child1
</div>
<div class="child2">
child2
</div>
</div>
```

you can also add many child div as you want , they will automatically make place in the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see below how i managed to do so without display:inline-block; and this will not break on any device unlike inline-block.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #F3F3F3;
  color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.container.two {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container.three {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
Margin 20px in between
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
</div>

Align boxes on left and right according to width
<div class="container two">
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
</div>

Align even spacing on left and right
<div class="container three">
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    BOX 1
  </div>
</div>
```